# How to order calculated ratios between 2 columns by ascending order?

Tags: sqlite

While querying a 2015 demographic survey database, I wanted to investigate which states, congressional districts and places in the USA had the highest african-american population percentages.

I have tries using "ORDER BY 'x' ASC;" in the end of the statement trying to order the values being calculated in ascending order. I managed to obtain the expected ratios, however, what I don't get is how to refer to those ratios, which I named 'x' above.

The statement I used for calculating the ratios is the following:

```
SELECT name, black, total_population,
ROUND(black * 100.0 / total_population, 1) as percent,
FROM states;
```

....aaaaand then I get stuck, not knowing how to order the results by the ratios in ascending order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **not** use quotes on the column alias:

```
ORDER BY 'x' ASC
         ^-^------------remove those
```

Otherwise you would order by a static string instead of a column.
Your query should looks like this:

```
SELECT name, 
       black, 
       total_population, 
       ROUND(black * 100.0 / total_population, 1) as percentages
FROM states
order by percentages asc
```

Comment: This solved my problem!!! I wasn't actually using quotation marks, just used them in the problem for illustration purposes. Anyhow. I think my problem was the order of the clauses in my statement. I was previously defining the table where the data would be queried FROM before ROUND.         Thank you very much!